# How does "or" work in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Why does the second operation computes to false? Does the "or" argument function differently in clojure? If so, how should I write the operation so it computes to true regardless of where the 0 is in the argument?

```
(= (or 0 1) 0) ; true

(= (or 1 0) 0) ; false
```

Comment: Clojure usually deals in _truthy_ and _falsy_ as the answers below point out. If you want `true` / `false` the `boolean` function will coerce to boolean. `(boolean 0)` yields `true`. `(boolean nil)` yields `false`. http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or` is no function - it is a macro.  it expands to `if` calls and by that the rules of `if` truth apply: `nil` or `false` are flasey, everything else is truthy - including `0`.

```
user=> (when 0 (println "true"))
true
nil
```

Your code expands to:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(or 1 0))
(let* [or__4238__auto__ 1] (if or__4238__auto__ or__4238__auto__ (clojure.core/or 0)))
```

So in short, `or`'s generated code returns the first truthy argument -- or the last one.

So if you want to know, if your list there contains any zero use something more appropriate:

```
user=> (some zero? [1 2 3])
nil
user=> (some zero? [1 2 0])
true
```

Or in case the `0` there is a param too:

```
user=> (some #{0} [1 2 3])
nil
user=> (some #{0} [1 2 0])
0
```

Comment: An alternative, if one has a choice of collection type, a set can act as a function and test for membership. `(#{1 2 3} 0)` yields `nil`. `(#{1 2 0} 0)` yields `0`.

Answer (score 5):

`(or)(or x)(or x & next)` - evaluates expressions **one at a time, from left to right**.

If form returns logical **true** value, `or` returns that value and doesn't evaluate any of the other expressions, otherwise it returns the
value of the last expression or `nil` if last expression are `falsy` (Source: [Clojure documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/or) ).

In first statement `(= (or 0 1) 0)` the (or 0 1) return `0` because it's is logical `true`( in clojure inly `nil` and `false` are falsy) then compare with `0` so result is `true`.

In second statement `(= (or 1 0) 0)` it returns `1` and compare it to `0` and returns false because they aren't equal.

Answer (score 3):

or returns the first non-false value or false.  So in your examples or will return the first number in the argument list, zero or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In Clojure `nil` and `false` are falsy, **everything else** is truthy.

If you want the result of the expression to be true when there is a zero in a list, you should test if some elements of the list are equal to zero.
`(some zero? [0 1])`

Answer (score 2):

You are testing logical values for equality. This is a code smell in most languages and worse in Clojure.

```
(or 0 1) ; 0
(or 1 0) ; 1
```

... since both `0` and `1` are logically true, and `or` returns its first logically true argument (or the last argument, if there is no true one). The only things that aren't true are `nil` and `false` (and its boxed form `Boolean/FALSE`).

The fact that `or` is a macro is incidental in this case.